# Ubuntu mate GUI not loading after installing NAS on Raspberry Pi

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, nas, ubuntu-mate

I had a Raspberry Pi and Ubuntu Mate running on that. One day I decided to attach a hard drive with that and convert that into a NAS. I completed the setup and I was able to access the NAS from my windows machine.

However, next day when I switched Raspberry Pi on, GUI didn't come up. It showed some icons on the desktop and then converted into Green colour.

I can't do anything with that now. I am clicking at places but unable to see any option. Pressing different keys also not making any difference.

Any idea what went wrong and how to correct it?

Comment: You need to go to the command line and check the X11 log, probably named something like `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. Focus on lines that report errors, labeled with `(EE)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am unable to open terminal. Even can't open anything. Any other option?

Comment: @PrashantBhardwaj I think ctrl+alt+f1 will get you to the console and ctrl+alt+f7 back to the desktop.
but as I said I'm not sure.

Comment: Unfortunately, ctrl+alt+f1 is not working. That's why I wrote in my question that no command is working.

Comment: You can connect the SD card or disk or whatever storage medium you use to another computer for checking.

Comment: Thanks for comments. When I insert SD card in windows laptop, I see two extra drives. system-boot(Y:) which has bunch of files but no file with name Xorg.0.log. With all those files there is just one folder in that with name as overlay and that folder also doesn't have file named as Xorg.0.log. One more removable disk can also be seen on inserting the SD card, however I am unable to open that, looks like it is bootable partition of SD card. Any idea how to check Xorg.0.log file in that in-accessible drive?

Comment: Got Ubuntu on another SD card and that is working with this Raspberry Pi, so Raspberry Pi is not a problem. It is that Ubuntu Mate on SD card, which is the problem. It would be great if I am able to fix the issue without loosing Ubuntu Mate as I made lot of changes in that and I don't want to restart from zero.